# Helm: value unchanged in the range loop

Tags: yaml, kubernetes-helm, helm3

Sorry in advance if this case has already been covered, I read many similar questions/answers but though they helped, I haven't managed to find the solution to my pb.

I needed to update my yaml value file to introduce a new key `networkpolicy` and iterate through it in an helm `range` loop:

Initial `value.yaml` file:

```
calico:
  spec:
    egress:
      - action: Allow
        destination:
          selector: app.kubernetes.io/name == 'test'
    order: 10
    types:
      - Egress
  spec:
    egress:
      - action: Allow
        destination:
          selector: app.kubernetes.io/name == 'test'
    order: 10
    types:
      - Egress
```

Updated `value.yaml` file:

```
calico:
  networkpolicy:
    name: micro-zoning.allow-egress-from-p-to-bitbucket
    spec:
      egress:
        - action: Allow
          destination:
            selector: app.kubernetes.io/name == 'test'
      order: 10
      types:
        - Egress
  networkpolicy:
    name: micro-zoning.allow-egress-from-p-to-papi
    spec:
      egress:
        - action: Allow
          destination:
            selector: app.kubernetes.io/name == 'p-api'
      order: 10
      types:
        - Egress
```

The helm template that processes it is this one:

```
{{- if .Values.calico -}}
{{- range .Values.calico.networkpolicy }}
apiVersion: crd.projectcalico.org/v1
kind: NetworkPolicy
metadata:
  name: {{ $.Values.calico.networkpolicy.name | default (printf "micro-zoning.%s" (include "test.fullname" $)) }}
  {{- include "test.globalMetadata" $ | nindent 2 }}
  labels:
    projectcalico.org/tier: micro-zoning
spec:
  tier: micro-zoning
  selector: app.kubernetes.io/name == "{{ include "test.name" $ }}"
  {{- with $.Values.calico.networkpolicy.spec }}
  {{- toYaml . | nindent 2 }}
  {{- end }}
---
{{- end }}
{{- end }}
```

It iterates twice (as expected) but the generated templates are identical, i.e. only data from the 2nd dictionary is printed:

```
---
apiVersion: crd.projectcalico.org/v1
kind: NetworkPolicy
metadata:
  name: micro-zoning.allow-egress-from-p-to-api
  
  namespace: test
  labels:
    projectcalico.org/tier: micro-zoning
spec:
  tier: micro-zoning
  selector: app.kubernetes.io/name == "test"
  egress:
  - action: Allow
    destination:
      selector: app.kubernetes.io/name == 'p-api'
  order: 10
  types:
  - Egress
---
apiVersion: crd.projectcalico.org/v1
kind: NetworkPolicy
metadata:
  name: micro-zoning.allow-egress-from-p-to-api
  
  namespace: test
  labels:
    projectcalico.org/tier: micro-zoning
spec:
  tier: micro-zoning
  selector: app.kubernetes.io/name == "test"
  egress:
  - action: Allow
    destination:
      selector: app.kubernetes.io/name == 'p-api'
  order: 10
  types:
  - Egress
---
```

Would you know what's happening?
I guess there's sthg wrong with the format of my `value.yaml` file but can't really figure out what.

Answer (score 1):

It may be caused by the scope.

`$` represents the root of values.

In the range loop, you should use `.` to represents the current element.

template

```yaml
{{- if .Values.calico -}}
{{- range .Values.calico }}
apiVersion: crd.projectcalico.org/v1
kind: NetworkPolicy
metadata:
  name: {{ .name | default (printf "micro-zoning.%s" (include "test.fullname" $)) }}
  labels:
    projectcalico.org/tier: micro-zoning
spec:
  tier: micro-zoning
  selector: app.kubernetes.io/name == "{{ include "test.name" $ }}"
  {{- with .networkpolicy.spec }}
  {{- toYaml . | nindent 2 }}
  {{- end }}
---
{{- end }}
{{- end }}
```

output:

```yaml
---
# Source: test/templates/calico.yaml
apiVersion: crd.projectcalico.org/v1
kind: NetworkPolicy
metadata:
  name: micro-zoning.test
  labels:
    projectcalico.org/tier: micro-zoning
spec:
  tier: micro-zoning
  selector: app.kubernetes.io/name == "test"
  egress:
  - action: Allow
    destination:
      selector: app.kubernetes.io/name == 'test'
  order: 10
  types:
  - Egress
---
# Source: test/templates/calico.yaml
apiVersion: crd.projectcalico.org/v1
kind: NetworkPolicy
metadata:
  name: micro-zoning.test
  labels:
    projectcalico.org/tier: micro-zoning
spec:
  tier: micro-zoning
  selector: app.kubernetes.io/name == "test"
  egress:
  - action: Allow
    destination:
      selector: app.kubernetes.io/name == 'p-api'
  order: 10
  types:
  - Egress
---
```

---

Ps: the `values.yaml` has some Syntax error which you provided.

There can't be two identical keys in a map. You should write them in an array to comply with the syntax. Like this:

Initial `value.yaml` file:

```yaml
calico:
  - spec:
    egress:
        - action: Allow
          destination:
            selector: app.kubernetes.io/name == 'test'
      order: 10
      types:
        - Egress
  - spec:
      egress:
        - action: Allow
          destination:
            selector: app.kubernetes.io/name == 'test'
      order: 10
      types:
        - Egress
```

Updated `value.yaml` file:

```yaml
calico:
  - networkpolicy:
      name: micro-zoning.allow-egress-from-p-to-bitbucket
      spec:
        egress:
          - action: Allow
            destination:
              selector: app.kubernetes.io/name == 'test'
        order: 10
        types:
          - Egress
  - networkpolicy:
      name: micro-zoning.allow-egress-from-p-to-papi
      spec:
        egress:
          - action: Allow
            destination:
              selector: app.kubernetes.io/name == 'p-api'
        order: 10
        types:
          - Egress
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately, I already tried this solution.

In the template file, when I remove the `$` and update the values file as you indicated for each, I got this error:
`Error: template: mychart/templates/calico.yaml:2:17: executing "mychart/templates/calico.yaml" at <.Values.calico.networkpolicy>: can't evaluate field networkpolicy in type interface {}`

Comment: In the template file, when I remove the `$` as you indicated and leave the values file as it is (w/o creating a list), I got this error (I tried this solution before posting):
`Error: template: mychart/templates/calico.yaml:6:11: executing "mychart/templates/calico.yaml" at <.name>: can't evaluate field name in type interface {}`

Comment: Sorry, I copied and pasted the previous version by mistake when I pasted it. Now I have updated the reply

Comment: But the above two resource names are still the same, this will also make mistakes in actual deployment, you need to avoid this situation

Answer (score 0):

I finally managed to work this out. I only had little experience with yaml and made some syntax errors.

The final yaml configuration file now looks like this:

```
calico:
  networkPolicy:
    - name: networkpolicy1
      spec:
        selector: test
        egress:
          - action: Allow
            destination:
              selector: app.kubernetes.io/name == 'chartname'
        order: 10
        types:
          - Egress
    - name: networkpolicy2
      spec:
        selector: chartname
        egress:
          - action: Allow
            destination:
              selector: app.kubernetes.io/name == 'test2'
        order: 10
        types:
          - Egress
```

And the helm template processing it looks like this:

```
{{- if .Values.calico -}}
{{- range .Values.calico.networkPolicy }}
apiVersion: crd.projectcalico.org/v1
kind: NetworkPolicy
metadata:
  name: {{ .name | default (printf "micro-zoning.%s" (include "chartname.fullname" $)) }}
  {{- include "chartname.globalMetadata" $ | nindent 2 }}
  labels:
    projectcalico.org/tier: micro-zoning
spec:
  tier: micro-zoning
  selector: app.kubernetes.io/name == {{ .spec.selector | default ((include "chartname.name" $)) }}
  {{- with .spec }}
  {{- toYaml . | nindent 2 }}
  {{- end }}
---
{{- end }}
{{- end }}
```

Note: this [yaml tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1uFVr15xDGg) helped.